# How to add plugin css and js to iframe

Tags: plugins, iframe

I am developing a plugin for chatbox(like Facebook) for site users. I am displaying users in right corner.if I click on user I am displaying omini chat window in iframe. But I am unable to get plugin css in that iframe page. Please let me know how can I get plugin css into iframe?

Comment: Unless the contents of the iframe are from the same domain, you can’t. And even then you need JavaScript and it has nothing to do with WordPress. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/217833

Comment: i can use direct link tag and script tag. But please let me know is it possible to use wp_enqueue_script('scriptjs', plugins_url( '/assets/js/script.js', NEO_URL ), array('jquery')  );

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking